# C++ Ошибка: is not valid integer value в функции

Tags: c++, c, c++builder, visual-c++

Есть функция:

```
int readCoord(String coord) {
        String pos;
        String whatFind = coord + "=";
        int startPos = PosEx(whatFind, XX);
        int endPos = PosEx(";", XX, startPos);
        pos = XX.SubString(startPos+2, endPos - startPos-2);
        int posConverted = StrToInt(pos);
        return posConverted;
        ShowMessage(pos);       // LOG
}
```

Использую так:

```
int posX = readCoord("x");
    Label4->Caption = posX;   
int posY = readCoord("y");
    Label5->Caption = posY;    
int posR = readCoord("R");
    Label6->Caption = posR;
```

Ничего не считает и выбивает ошибку:

> '' is not valid integer value

Не пойму, где я что сделал не так

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться дебаггером.

Comment: Наверное падает StrToInt(pos);, т.к. pos  равно пустой строке

Comment: А в какой строке падает? Чему равны переменные, с которыми код работает в этой строке?

Comment: Ну у вас кавычка попадает в вызов `atoi()` где-то в глубине этой штуковины.

Answer (score 1):

1. Что такое `ХХ` в реализации ф-ции `readCoord()`?
2. > `Label5->Caption = IntToStr(posY); // обратите внимание на`**`IntToStr`**